# What does error "tx_insufficient_balance" mean for Change Trust?

Tags: token, trustline

I have created an issuing account and a distributing account for a new token.

I changed trust and sent a payment of 144,000 of this token from the issuing account to the distributing account.

I created a third account and attempted to trust the issuing account, getting the error "tx_insufficient_funds" and if this information helps from the "envelope_xdr" [here is the link](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAEyIZMJe2kpL8Iu6Etfh38ZgBiSLxhxh16tGbyW05yj8AAAAZAD83C8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAYAAAABQ1VQAAAAAABceU8e%2BKFx9A2iWsucGziwRwlunrVwc8Dr9wG6S1S2FwAAAAAGjneAAAAAAAAAAAG05yj8AAAAQJsKof3lPDCD%2B6E2LeoLjx9bae6GZ1i22dEGnGSQMouKHh9CdUoxjK2EOvuzUVWVImlbWfM%2FtXs5p9U87fX5jwI%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope).

I do not see "tx_insufficient_funds" as an error in [the docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#change-trust) for Change Trust.

Any idea which account has insufficient funds? The customer account that i'm using as the Source Account has 1 XLM added as the only transaction, and the issuing account has 22 XLM added and 144,000 of my new token deducted, that was paid to the distributing account.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a trust line, the minimum required balance of the account increases by 1 x base reserve.  In order to hold a trust line in your new account, it would need a balance of 1.5 XLM.

From the documentation on [minimum account balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance):

> All Stellar accounts must maintain a minimum balance of lumens. Any transaction that would reduce an account’s balance to less than the minimum will be rejected with an INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE error.
>
> The minimum balance is calculated using the base reserve, which is 0.5 XLM:
>
> (2 + # of entries) × base reserve
>
> The minimum balance for a basic account is 2 × base reserve. Each additional entry costs the base reserve. Entries include:
>
> - Trustlines
> - Offers
> - Signers
> - Data entries